# Two children with the same key in React

Tags: reactjs, key, addition

Application works, my classes really adds a new element but I see below warning in console!

> Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `[object
>   Object]`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their
>   identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be
>   duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could
>   change in a future version.
>       in div (created by ContentBody)
>       in ContentBody

**Here is my render part :**

```
 return (
            <div ref={this.myRef} style={this.state.myHomeStyle} >
              {this.state.elements.map((i: any) => {
                console.log(">>i>>>>", i);
                return <span style={i.myStyle} key={i} >{i}</span>;
              })}
            </div>
        );

// Where i init 
 public componentDidMount() {

    console.log('componentDidMount');
    this.myDOM  = this.myRef.current;
    this.myDOM.addEventListener(myEventsList.adaptCss, this.adaptCss);

    this.add(12,this.INLINE_TEST_ELE, null);
    this.add(13,this.INLINE_TEST_ELE, null);

  }


// Function add 
private add = (id: number, content: any, event: any ) => {

    let localArr: any[] = [];
    let mEvent: any = null;

    if (event !== undefined) {
      mEvent = event;
    }

    localArr = this.state.elements;
    localArr.push(React.createElement("div", { key: id , onClick : mEvent }, content));

    this.setState(
      {
        elements: localArr,
        visibility : true,
      },
    );

  }
```

Any suggestions?

Update: 
 Here is the link for my starter project:
 https://github.com/zlatnaspirala/react-vs-typescript-starter

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can pass another parameter within your map function like so:

```
this.state.elements.map((element, index) => {
   return <span style={element.myStyle} key={index} >{element}</span>;
});
```

The second parameter of the `Array.prototype.map` function actually contains the current index of the particular element in that array.

This way, you'll be sure that your key is not duplicated.

Comment: We are not encouraged to use index as key

Comment: Then maybe use the element's id as the key or any other properties of the object that is unique. I need to also know the contents of the `this.state.elements` please state it on your question so we are all aware.

Comment: Warning! Using the index in a map may work but is not a good idea. When you swap out items in a list, the key will stay the same and that will *fool* React into thinking it doesn't need to update. See this blog post for a full explanation  https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318

Comment: From https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys: "When you don’t have stable IDs for rendered items, you may use the item index as a key as a last resort. [...] We don’t recommend using indexes for keys if the order of items may change. This can negatively impact performance and may cause issues with component state. [...] If you choose not to assign an explicit key to list items then React will default to using indexes as keys." Also see https://robinpokorny.medium.com/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318

Answer (score 5):

You are passing element not index. And if your element is same then the error is being thrown. To pass the index use second param:

```
.map((element, index)=>
```

Now, using `index` will give you different key.

Comment: Using index is not a good choice.

Comment: From https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys: "When you don’t have stable IDs for rendered items, you may use the item index as a key as a last resort. [...] We don’t recommend using indexes for keys if the order of items may change. This can negatively impact performance and may cause issues with component state. [...] If you choose not to assign an explicit key to list items then React will default to using indexes as keys." Also see https://robinpokorny.medium.com/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318

Answer (score 3):

See this for more understanding in "key" related warnings and best practices

```
 function ListItem(props) {
  // Correct! There is no need to specify the key here:
  return <li>{props.value}</li>;
}

function NumberList(props) {
  const numbers = props.numbers;
  const listItems = numbers.map((number) =>
    // Correct! Key should be specified inside the array.
    <ListItem key={number.toString()}
              value={number} />

  );
  return (
    <ul>
      {listItems}
    </ul>
  );
}

const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
ReactDOM.render(
  <NumberList numbers={numbers} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Visit this link https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#extracting-components-with-keys for more information