# Two children with the same key in React component

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I know that there are similar questions to this one, I've tried them both [(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52219852/two-children-with-the-same-key-in-react), [(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41703160/react-warning-flattenchildren-encountered-two-children-with-the-same-key) and didn't work for my case.

Having an array of objects on props:

```
this.props.items = [ { name: 'a', price: 10},
                     { name: 'b', price: 20},
                     { name: 'c', price: 10},
                     { name: 'd', price: 30},
                   ];
```

I want to create a list with all the price options and put that unique values on a dropdown so I'm doing this:

```
  const priceOptions = [{ text: '', value: '' }];

  const prices = [
    ...new Set(this.props.items.map(item => item.price)),
  ];
  prices.forEach(price => {
    if (price) {
      priceOptions.push({
        key: price,
        text: price,
        value: price,
      });
    }
```

this code throws the error:

> Warning: Encountered two children with the same key,
>   `ellipsisItem-NaN`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain
>   their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to
>   be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could
>   change in a future version.

Don't know what does `ellipsisItem` mean, that variable is not in the project.

I've read on the other questions' answers that it should be used the index instead of the element. So I changed it to:

```
  const prices = [
    ...new Set(this.props.items.map(item => item.price)),
  ];
  prices.forEach((price, index) => {
    if (price) {
      priceOptions.push({
        key: index,
        text: price,
        value: price,
      });
    }
  });
```

but it throws the **same error**.

It is possible that in the array of objects to have more objects with same price but on dropdown it should show only the unique values.

From `10, 20, 10, 30` to `10, 20, 30`

**UPDATE**
I'm adding also where it is rendered.

```
return (
  <Layout>
     ...
     <Dropdown
        placeholder="Price"
        onChange={this.searchHandlerPrice}
        options={priceOptions}
     />
```

and the searchHandlerPrice:

```
  searchHandlerPrice = (event, data) => {
    const { getItems } = this.props;
    geItems({
      name: this.props.query.name,
      price: data.value,
    });
  };
```

and **< Dropdown >**:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Dropdown } from 'semantic-ui-react';

import './Dropdown.styles.scss';

export default ({placeholder, options, onChange}) => {
    return (
        <Dropdown className="hello-dropdown"
            placeholder={placeholder}
            search
            selection
            options={options}
            onChange={onChange}
            clearable
        />
    );
};
```

Comment: To me it looks like a problem with whatever creates the `ellipsisItem` key. Have you tried looking for where that is coming from?

Comment: Hi! You didn't show the code where you actually render the list in a React component. Could you do that?

Comment: I searched for that variable but it does not appear on results. It's not in the project

Comment: @nicoqh, updated

Comment: Is Dropdown component your own or from some library?

Comment: @artfulbeest, it is mine. I added it to the end of the question

Comment: Still can not reproduce this on my end ... how about component where you render  'list with all the price options' ?

Comment: Sorry!, Can't join now..but I think problem could be where you render that list, I have tried to render options with Dropdown and it works

Comment: I prefer using my array indices as element keys, this guarantees no two children will have same key

Comment: can you write an answer with that? would be helpful

Comment: Are you sure error comes from dropdown? What if you comment it ? If yes, what does contain options, are we sure its an array [{item:'', value:''}] can you dump it ? NB: I would hint that you should ensure to give string, not number (for text and value)

Comment: prepare living, editable [example] on codesandbox

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where the problem lies. However, I recreated this problem using MATERIAL UI's SELECT tag and everything seems to be working fine.

In App.js

```
class App extends React.Component {
  items = [
    { name: "a", price: 10 },
    { name: "b", price: 20 },
    { name: "c", price: 10 },
    { name: "d", price: 30 }
  ];

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Select items={this.items} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

in Select.js

```
export default function SelectForm(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [price, setPrice] = React.useState("");
  const [uniquePrice, setUniquePrice] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const newPrice = [...new Set(props.items.map(item => item.price))];
    setUniquePrice(newPrice);
  }, [props]);

  const handleChange = event => {
    setPrice(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
        <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Price List</InputLabel>
        <Select value={price} onChange={handleChange}>
          {uniquePrice.map(price => (
            <MenuItem key={price} value={price}>
              {price}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </Select>
        <p>Selected Value: {price}</p>
      </FormControl>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Checkout the following codeSandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-dropdown-yybhq

Hope this helps